# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\index.php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my code I'm getting this error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\index.php on line 11

#### index.php

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/function/database.php';

$sql = 'SELECT id, title, description, price FROM products';

$result = getDB()->query($sql);
require __DIR__.'/templates/main.php';
```

#### ./function/database.php

```
<?php 
function getDB() { 
    static $db;

    if ($db instanceof PDO){ 
        return $db; 
    }

    require_once CONFIG_DIR.'/database.php'; 

    $dsn = sprintf("myqsl:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s",DB_HOST,DB_DATABASE,DB_CHARSET); 

    return $db; 
}
```

Comment: What is `getDB()` and where is it coming from?

Comment: You create the value for `$dsn`, but don't create a `\PDO` object for the connection.

Comment: You're not creating a database connection here at all. You create a DSN string with `$dsn`, but then go right to sending `$db` back

Comment: @aynber this is the code                                                                                                
<?php
define('DB_DATABASE','shop');
define('DB_USERNAME','shop');
define('DB_PASSWORD','123456');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_CHARSET','utf8');

Comment: That's still just definitions. At no point do you create a PDO connection.

Comment: i now mad this <?php

function getDB(){
  static $db;
  if($db instanceof PDO){
    return $db;
  }
  require_once CONFIG_DIR.'/database.php';
  $dsn = sprintf("myqsl:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s".);
  $db = new PDO($dsn,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
  return $db;
}

Comment: and got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\function\database.php on line 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to create `PDO` connection:

```php
<?php 
function getDB(){ 
    static $db; 
    if($db instanceof PDO){ 
        return $db; 
    } 
    require_once CONFIG_DIR.'/database.php'; 
    $dsn = sprintf("myqsl:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s",DB_HOST,DB_DATABASE,DB_CHARSET); 
    $db = new PDO($dsn); // ← HERE
    return $db; 
}
```